# jquery hover function in views template (drupal 6)

Tags: views, javascript

I have a views template called: **views-view-fields--video--block-1.tpl.php**

Inside that file i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.last-vid-poster').hover(function() {
        $(this).parents('.last-vid-block').find('a.play_button').fadeIn('slow');
      }, function() {
        $(this).parents('.last-vid-block').find('a.play_button').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
  });
</script>

<?php

print '<div class="last-vid-block">';

print '<div style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">'. $fields['field_video_embed']->content.'</div>';

print '<h3 class="video-block">'. $fields['title']->content .'</h3>';

$hover_play = l('<img src="/' . path_to_theme() . '/img/play-button.png" />', 'node/' . $row->nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'play_button', 'style' => 'display: none'), 'html' => true));

print $hover_play;

print '</div>'; // vgrid

?>
```

As you can see in my JS code at the top of the template, i'm printing `$hover_play` when user hovers over `.last-vid-block .imagecache` object, so it fades In then fades Out, that works, yeah.

But the problem is -> i have in that views block 4 nodes with that markup, so when i hover over just one `.last-vid-block .imagecache` that $hover_play shows on all 4 objects... How to separate them - if i hover just 1st object `$hover_play` shows only at 1st object etc... 
Thanks in advance!

```
ATTENTION! Edited js code at the top! It works as intended, is there any erros in that code?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue was that you were targeting all play buttons at once with your JS, the second problem that came up in the comments below is that your play button is on top of your `.imagecache` object and your `.play_button` is taking away the mouse focus, thus firing "hover out"

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.last-vid-block').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('a.play_button').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('a.play_button').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

The downside to this, however, is that if you hover over the title on the right side (outside of the `.imagecache`) object, your still going to get the fade in/out effect triggered...

If that is not what you want then you could try altering the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.last-vid-poster').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('a.play_button').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('a.play_button').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
  });
</script>

<?php

print '<div class="last-vid-block">';

print '<div class="last-vid-poster" style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">';

print $fields['field_video_embed']->content;

$hover_play = l('<img src="/' . path_to_theme() . '/img/play-button.png" />', 'node/' . $row->nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'play_button', 'style' => 'display: none'), 'html' => true));

print $hover_play;

print '</div>';

print '<h3 class="video-block">'. $fields['title']->content .'</h3>';


print '</div>'; // vgrid

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But now when i hover over a.play_button that button fades..

Comment: I'm not sure.  Your code above shows only part of the problem.  Can you add the rendered HTML to the question?  Also -- do you have a link to the page?

Comment: http://beta.ruh.kz a block called "СВЕЖЕЕ ВИДЕО"

Comment: ah the problem is that the link is on top of the imagecache object, so when it appears it takes away the "focus" of the mouse and jQuery reads that as "hover out" -- i will update my answer above

Comment: thanks, +50 given to you! Also didn't understand why you have removed .parents will it work without that?

Comment: i removed it because the markup changed in the template alteration i made -- jquery no longer needs to look for the parent because it's calling the element from a higher level

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is too wide. You should use context

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.last-vid-block').each(function() {
      var $block = $(this);
      $('.imagecache', $block).hover(
        function() {
          $('a.play_button', $block).fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
          $('a.play_button', $block).fadeOut('slow');
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```

It's better to place the js into views-view--video--block.tpl.php (you should check the exact name) as in your current scenario the code is executed #videos times.

Comment: Thanks, but when i hover over a.play_button it fades. It should not fade when i hover over a.play_button, how to make that?